# How to increase max_locks_per_transaction in MacOSX

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x

I've been performing kind of intensive schema dropping and creating over a PostgreSQL server,

> ERROR: out of shared memory
>
> HINT: You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.

I need to increase max_locks_per_transaction but how can i increase it in MAC OSX

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-locks.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the `postgres.conf` file. The parameter is defined there. On windows I found it in the data directory so I guess it will be the same for Mac OSX.